# Div tag being prematurely closed

Tags: html

I'm working on a new webpage for my blog @ http://bornsquishy.ca

I'm also trying to use a grid system by http://gridiculo.us/

The problem that I'm having is the div class "grid" is being closed off at the end of the header without a closing div tag, and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Here is the code from the header.php after the closing head tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="main"><!-- this encompasses the entire Web site -->
<header id="header">        
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="c3">
                <div class="logo">
                        <?php if(of_get_option('logo_type') == 'text_logo'){?>
                        <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                                                <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                                <h2><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h2>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <?php } else { ?>

                                    <?php if(of_get_option('logo_url') != ''){ ?>
                                                 <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" id="logo"><img src="<?php echo of_get_option('logo_url', "" ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"></a>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" id="logo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"></a>
                                        <?php } ?>

                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div><!-- .logo -->
            </div><!-- .c3 -->

            <div class="c8">
                    <nav class="primary">
                        <div class="menu-holder">
                            <div class="menu-left">
                                    <div class="menu-right">
                                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'container'       => 'ul', 
                                    'menu_class'      => 'sf-menu', 
                                    'menu_id'         => 'topnav',
                                    'depth'           => 0,
                                    'theme_location' => 'header_menu' 
                                    )); 
                                     ?>
                                    </div><!--.menu-right-->
                                </div><!--.menu-left-->
                        </div><!--.menu-holder-->
                    </nav><!--.primary-->
            </div><!--.c8-->

            <div class="c1 end">
                <div id="rss-feed">
                        <img src="/images/rss-logo.png">    
                    </div><!--.rss-feed-->
                </div><!-- .c1 end-->
        </div><!-- .row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="c8">
                <div class="title">
                                    <img src="/images/title.png">
                            </div><!--.title-->
            </div><!--.c8-->
            <div class="c4 end">
                <div id="widget-header">
                            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Header' ) ) : ?>
                                <!-- Widgetized Header -->
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </div><!--#widget-header-->
            </div><!-- .c4 end -->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    <!--.grid left open-->                         
</header>
<!--#main left open-->
```

Let me know if more code/info is needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments say `<!--.grid left open-->`, does this mean you want to close the `div.grid` element **after** the closing `</header>`? If so, you can't do that because the `div` was opened inside the `header`, so it must be closed before the header is closed. HTML elements can't "overlap" each other.

If you're using Chrome developer tools or similar to inspect the markup, the browser will have seen the error and "fixed" your HTML structure in order to display it.

You either need to put the opening `div` before or after the header, or close the `div` before the end of the header.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted the grid left open, so I put the grid tags outside the header tags and it worked as I intended.